# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices : Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to save email on office 365 using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll (EWS Apis)

```
     EmailMessage f_ObjEWSMail  = new EmailMessage(objExchangeService);
     f_ObjEWSMail.Save(p_objFoderID); // Throwing error here
```

It throws exception randomly :

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

or sometimes it throws:

> The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> Stack Strace ::    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Save(FolderId parentFolderId)
>      at Office365EWSWriter.Office365Engine.SaveMail(EmailMessage p_objEWSMailItem, FolderId p_objFoderID)

Please suggest solution.

Comment: Hi Renuka, What is `MailMessageObj` in the above code? and you are fetching mail message from which mail account?

Comment: sorry.. Its f_ObjEWSMail ..

Comment: It would be great if you add few more information about the code that you are using.

Comment: I just want to add that specific mail (f_ObjEWSMail) to specific folder (FolderId is mentioned as p_objFoderID) of office 365 mailbox using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll.

Comment: I am uploading 2 mails at a time using multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are due to issues with the underlying transport connectivity (eg your network connection to the cloud) because your dealing with the cloud you can't guarantee the network 100% (eg vs Onprem where you just connecting to the server over a switch). All you can do in this instance is catch the error and retry. The EWS Managed API is using HttpWebRequest to send and receive the SOAP packets so these errors are generated by this class at the client (if you want to chase those errors further then i would suggest searching Stackoverflow for those errors on that class). If you try using your code from a cloud based Virtual Machine (or service) like AWS or Azure you should find the instances of these errors a lot lower because the underlying network connectivity is much more reliable.